# ¿Cómo hacer una factura de un cajero de productos a archivo txt?

Tags: python

Esto es lo que llevo del código, solo me falta la parte de que de la opción de generar una factura de la caja en un archivo .txt, quería ejemplos de como realizar esa parte, aun soy un novato.

El problema me pide:
Al ingresar a esta opción el usuario ingresara los datos de cada producto para realizar una factura de lo que el cliente está
interesado en comprar. La cantidad de productos es variable y se le debe
preguntar al usuario si desea agregar otro producto. Los datos que el
cliente debe introducir son: código del artículo, descripción del artículo,
cantidad a comprar, precio unitario.

Al final el sistema debe calcular el total por línea, es decir, si el cliente llevar 3 productos con un precio individual de
$3.25, el total de la línea va a ser (3*3.25) = $9.75.

Al final de la compra se debe calcular el subtotal de la factura y calcular el impuesto de forma general de 10%. (se debe expresar por separado este
impuesto) y luego se debe sumar el impuesto con el subtotal para tener el
valor total a pagar de la factura.

AL terminar de generar la factura le debe salir usuario si desea grabar la
factura y eso generar que se cree un archivo de texto plano con el nombre
de factura.txt que va tener el total de la factura. Si el cliente indica que no va a grabar la factura, debe regresar al menú principal y no se graba nada en el archivo plano. La forma como se va grabar es agregando líneas al archivo Txt. Es decir, que no debe reescribir el archivo, si no agregar la línea cuando sea necesario.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import tkinter.messagebox

class GUI:

    def __init__(self,ventana):
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.cajaCantidad = IntVar()
        self.CajaImpuesto = DoubleVar()
        self.cajaSubTotal = DoubleVar()
        self.cajaTotal = DoubleVar()
        self.Articulo = StringVar()
        self.Codigo = StringVar()
        self.Descripcion = StringVar()
        self.Precio = DoubleVar()
        self.total = 0
        self.totalsub=0
        impuesto = 0
        self.dibujarComponentes()
        #ENTRY PRECIO Y ARTICULO
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.Articulo).place(x=10,y=35)
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.Precio).place(x=460,y=35)
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.Codigo).place(x=160,y=35)
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.Descripcion).place(x=310,y=35)

        

    def dibujarComponentes(self):
        self.ventana.title("Caja Registrado")
        self.ventana.geometry("1225x470")
        Label(self.ventana,text="Producto: ").place(x=10,y=10)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Codigo: ").place(x=160,y=10)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Descripcion: ").place(x=310,y=10)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Precio: ").place(x=460,y=10)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Seleciona la cantidad: ").place(x=10,y=60)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Sub-total: ").place(x=1020,y=400)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Impuesto: ").place(x=1020,y=420)
        Label(self.ventana,text="Total: ").place(x=1020,y=440)
       
        
        #ENTRYS GENERALES
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.cajaCantidad).place(x=10,y=85)
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.cajaSubTotal).place(x=1090,y=400)
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.CajaImpuesto).place(x=1090,y=420)
        Entry(self.ventana,textvariable=self.cajaTotal).place(x=1090,y=440)


        Button(self.ventana,text="Agregar",command=self.agregarProducto).place(x=10,y=110)

        self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(self.ventana,columns=("Codigo","Descripcion","Cantidad","Precio Unitario","Subtotal"))
        self.tabla.heading("#0",text="Producto")
        self.tabla.heading("Codigo",text="Codigo")
        self.tabla.heading("Descripcion",text="Descripcion")
        self.tabla.heading("Cantidad",text="Cantidad")
        self.tabla.heading("Precio Unitario",text="Precio Unitario")
        self.tabla.heading("Subtotal",text="Subtotal")
        self.tabla.place(x=10,y=150)

    def agregarProducto(self):
        
    
        #PROCESO DE CALCULO
        producto = self.Articulo.get()
        precio = self.Precio.get()
        cantidad = self.cajaCantidad.get()
        subtotal = float(precio)*int(cantidad)
        self.totalsub = self.totalsub + subtotal
        impuesto ="{:.3f}".format(self.totalsub*0.1)
        total=self.totalsub+float(impuesto) 
        self.tabla.insert("",END,text=producto,values=(self.Codigo.get(),self.Descripcion.get(),cantidad,precio,"$"+str(subtotal)))
        
        
        #SETT PRINCIPALES
        self.CajaImpuesto.set(impuesto)
        self.cajaTotal.set(total) 
        self.cajaSubTotal.set(f"${self.totalsub}")

    

obj = GUI(Tk())
obj.ventana.mainloop()
```